# Covariance and conditional probability

Tags: probability, covariance

This may be completely trivial, but wanted to understand the following better: Let's say we know the covariance of two random variables $X, Y$ - is there anything intelligent we can say about the expected value of $X$, given an observation $Y = y$?

I.e. what (if any) is the relationship of $cov(X,Y)$ and $\mathbb{E}(X|Y = y)$?

If required, we may assume that we know $\mathbb{E}X=\mu$ and $\mathbb{E}{Y}=\gamma$.

Comment: Are you aware that E(X|Y) is a random variable, not a number?

Comment: You are right, thanks - edited the question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}}$
$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{\mathbb{Cov}}}$
$\newcommand{\Pr}{\operatorname{\mathbb{Pr}}}$
Just this:
$$\begin{align}
\E(XY) & = \sum_{\forall y} y\E(X\mid Y=y)\Pr(Y=y)
& = \int_{\bf Y} y \E(X\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)\operatorname{d}y
\\
\\ \Cov(X,Y) & = \E(XY)-\E(X)\E(Y) 
\\ & = \underbrace{-\mu\gamma + \sum_{\forall y} y\E(X\mid Y=y)\Pr(Y=y)}_{\text{discrete random variable}}
& = \underbrace{-\mu\gamma + \int_{\bf Y} y \E(X\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)\operatorname{d}y}_{\text{continuous random variable}}
\end{align}$$